# Trying to match a range value within a list to user input

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, range

I'm trying to match the input value to a range value in a list. Like I have a list of games and a range of how many players per game. I'm trying to take the user input and return a game that falls in that category based on the range values in its list. If the user inputs 3 I'd like to print the options that all have a 3 within their range but this doesn't output anything. I'm assuming the if-statement output is false but I don't know how to correct it.

```
games = [
    ['Game 1' , 'short' , list(range(2,6))],
    ['Game 2' , 'short' , list(range(2,7))],
    ['Game 3' , 'long' , list(range(5,10))]
]

players = input('players?\n\n')

options=[]
for game in games:
    if game[2] == int((players)):
        options.append(game[0])
        print(options)
```

Comment: A `range` object supports the following properties that solves this. Given `r=range(10,20,2)` then `r` has `.start, .stop, .step` properties that would be `10,20,2` in this case. It also supports `in` so `12 in r` would the `True` and `13 in r` would be `False`. You do NOT need to convert the range to a list.

Comment: Please be consider with people spending time helping you anytime you change the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix to your code includes two steps:

1. Think about how you will add another game in your list.

   - Right now `game` first gets the value `short` and then the value `[2,3,4,5]`
   - One fix would be to make `games` a list of lists or a list of tuples e.g. `games = [('short', list(range(2, 6))), ('shorter',list(range(2,4)))]`
2. Think about how you read the number of players.

   - Right now `players` is of type `string`
   - One fix would be to make an integer right after reading it e.g. `players = int(input('players\n'))`
3. Think about how you check if a number is in a range

   - `number == list_of_numbers` will always be `false`
   - One fix would be to check `if number in list_of_numbers:`

---

##### This should be a comment but I don't have enough rep yet

This will get your code working, but then you can think of others ways to make it do what you want. Like, do you need to store the whole range of players or just the minimum and maximum values and check that the number given is between them? Or, will you print that there is a game that can be played with that many people, or print the names of the games?